# Button click makes gui freezes

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I want to call method from jButton. But when I hit the button, the GUI freezes. I've done so many research, and of course I know this kind of question has asked many times but I still can't find the solution. So I'm just gonna ask myself.

here's my method:

```
     private void c2(){
    try{
        jTextArea1.setText("");
        int n = 0;
        float bnyAB,bnyA,bnyB=0;
        float supp,conf=0;
        for(int a=0;a<dt.size();a++)
        {
           n++;
           for(int b=0+n;b<dt.size();b++)
           {
               bnyAB=sql2.c2(dt.get(a).getKode_barang(), dt.get(b).getKode_barang());
               bnyA=dt.get(a).getNilai();
               bnyB=dt.get(b).getNilai();
               supp=bnyAB/Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText())*100;
               if(supp>=Float.parseFloat(jSpinner1.getValue().toString()))
               {
                   conf=(bnyAB/bnyA)*100;
                   if(conf>=Float.parseFloat(jSpinner2.getValue().toString()))
                       jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText()+" Jika membeli \" "+dt.get(a).getNama_barang()+" \" maka akan membeli \" "+dt.get(b).getNama_barang()+" \" dengan Supp "+atur.format(supp)+"% dan Conf "+atur.format(conf)+"% \n");

                   conf=(bnyAB/bnyB)*100;
                   if(conf>=Float.parseFloat(jSpinner2.getValue().toString()))
                      jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText()+" Jika membeli \" "+dt.get(b).getNama_barang()+" \" maka akan membeli \" "+dt.get(a).getNama_barang()+" \" dengan Supp "+atur.format(supp)+"% dan Conf "+atur.format(conf)+"% \n"); 
               }
           }
        }
    }catch(Exception a){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    this.revalidate();
}


private void c3(){
    int n=0, m=0, o=0;
    String item1,item2,item3="";
    float bnyABC,bnyAB=0;
    float supp,conf=0;

    for (int a=0;a<dt.size();a++){
        n++;
        for(int b=0+n;b<dt.size();b++){
            for(int c=0+b+1;c<dt.size();c++){
                bnyABC = sql2.c3(dt.get(a).getKode_barang(), dt.get(b).getKode_barang(),dt.get(c).getKode_barang());
                supp=bnyABC/Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText())*100;

                if(supp>=Float.parseFloat(jSpinner1.getValue().toString()))
                {
                    bnyAB=sql2.c2(dt.get(a).getKode_barang(), dt.get(b).getKode_barang());
                    conf=(bnyABC/bnyAB)*100;

                    if(conf>=Float.parseFloat(jSpinner2.getValue().toString()))
                        jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText()+" Jika membeli \" "+dt.get(a).getNama_barang()+" \" dan \" "+dt.get(b).getNama_barang()+" \" maka akan membeli \" "+dt.get(c).getNama_barang()+" \" dengan Supp "+atur.format(supp)+"% dan Conf "+atur.format(conf)+"% \n");

                    bnyAB=sql2.c2(dt.get(a).getKode_barang(), dt.get(c).getKode_barang());
                    conf=(bnyABC/bnyAB)*100;
                    if(conf>=Float.parseFloat(jSpinner2.getValue().toString()))
                        jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText()+" Jika membeli \" "+dt.get(a).getNama_barang()+" \" dan \" "+dt.get(c).getNama_barang()+" \" maka akan membeli \" "+dt.get(b).getNama_barang()+" \" dengan Supp "+atur.format(supp)+"% dan Conf "+atur.format(conf)+"% \n");

                    bnyAB=sql2.c2(dt.get(b).getKode_barang(), dt.get(c).getKode_barang());
                    conf=(bnyABC/bnyAB)*100;
                    if(conf>=Float.parseFloat(jSpinner2.getValue().toString()))
                        jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText()+" Jika membeli \" "+dt.get(b).getNama_barang()+" \" dan \" "+dt.get(c).getNama_barang()+" \" maka akan membeli \" "+dt.get(a).getNama_barang()+" \" dengan Supp "+atur.format(supp)+"% dan Conf "+atur.format(conf)+"% \n");
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

actionPerformed button to call method:

```
    private void analisis2BtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    c2();
    c3();
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is likely the same as all the other similar questions, calling long-running code on the event thread, and the solution is the same, don't do that. Read, no study the [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) tutorial.

Comment: so how should I call my method? I still don't unserstand. I'm still new in java and netbeans tbh

Comment: 1. Create a SwingWorker. 2. Make any long-running calls within the worker's `doInBackground()` method. 3. Do not update GUI components from this same method. 4. Communicate to the GUI via the worker's publish/process method pair, or in its `done()` method after the worker has completed its actions. 5. Read or re-read the link given above.

Comment: thanks it's sloved, my GUI is no longer freeze. but I have new problem here. When calling my method c2 and c3, it shows nothing